# How to print high volume of pages with very little text?

Tags: printing, laser-printer

I need to print a large number of letter sized pages. Each of these pages will have very little text (e.g. serial no.). I will be using a mono laser printer (probably Lexmark T654). The page volume may exceed the printer's monthly duty cycle (300k).

Is there any driver or printer setting that will help reduce mechanical damage and let me print beyond max duty cycle (by resetting the counter of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max duty cycle is used by the manufacturer to illustrate what they consider the maximum number of pages to be printed within a month while maintaining the maximum lifespan of that device.

It's not a hard rule and your printer probably won't keel over and die when you exceed it.

The problem occurs when you exceed this limit repeatedly. In which case you should buy a printer capable of handling your printing needs anyway.

If this is a one-time job, it's highly unlikely your printer will fail due to it. Just make sure you schedule some quality one-on-one time with the printer before and after to make sure it understands you really do love and appreciate it.

Your major concern, then, is to minimize cost. This is done by choosing whatever economy print modes there are on the device.